# svg-android import not working?

Tags: android, svg

Trying to follow the tutorial here https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial

However, when I try the line

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
```

the getSVGFromResource appears red and shows: Cannot resolve symbol 'getSVGFromResource'

The import statements are

```
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;
```

so I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: It does work (tested in Eclipse, API Level 2.2+).

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using?  Assuming its Android Studio, have you added svg-android as a dependency?

Go to Project->Project Structure->app->Dependencies.